# Returning one result per id in SQL in a joined table

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, left-join, knex.js

I have one table of users.

```
users

| user_id | name   |
| ------- | ------ |
| 1       | Jerry  |
| 2       | George |
| 3       | Elaine |
| 4       | Kramer |
```

I have one table that links roles to users, and roles are assigned at a tree.

```
user_roles

| user_id | role_id | tree_id |
| ------- | ------- | ------- |
| 1       | 5       | 1       |
| 1       | 5       | 2       |
| 2       | 6       | 1       |
| 3       | 7       | 1       |
| 4       | 8       | 1       |
```

I need to only return results where a user's role is assigned at a certain tree_id, so I'm checking all the roles and trees. At the end I want it to return one row per user.

I'm using [Knex](http://knexjs.org/) and doing a query that looks like:

```
knex('users')
  .leftJoin('user_roles', {'user.user_id': 'user_roles.user_id'})
  .whereIn('user_roles.tree_id', arrayOfTreeIds)
  .andWhere(moreFilters)
```

```
SELECT *
FROM users
LEFT JOIN user_roles on users.user_id = user_roles.user_id
WHERE user_roles.tree_id in (1, 2, 3)
```

I'm getting five results back instead of four, though. If I try to `SELECT DISTINCT` it tells me I need to `GROUP BY`, but I can't get that to work. What do I need to do to get only one result per user id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a user that matches on two different `tree_id`s, so this multiplies the rows.

In pure SQL, you could use `exists` instead of a `join`:

```
SELECT *
FROM users u
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM user_roles ur
    WHERE ur.user_id = u.user_id AND ur.tree_id in (1, 2, 3)
)
```

Another option is aggregation:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_roles ur on u.user_id = ur.user_id
WHERE ur.tree_id in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

I changed the `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, because that's, in essence, what you want (and what your original query does).

You can even list the matched roles with string aggregation:

```
SELECT u.*, STRING_AGG(ur.tree_id::text, ',' ORDER BY ur.tree_id) tree_ids
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_roles ur on u.user_id = ur.user_id
WHERE ur.tree_id in (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY u.user_id
```

Disclaimer: I don't know how to write this in knex!

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bb42c4d4a3d563310f8794e643781c75)**

Comment: Hi! Thank you for all your quick, detailes responses. Trying your middle one first as it was easiest to translate to knex (unfortunately I have to use it) but I keep getting the error: `"user_roles.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` and I can't figure out why...

Comment: I've tried the first one as well and get `column "user.user_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`...

Comment: Unfortunately the 2nd one didn't work for me, but the first one works if I add a group by. It doesn't give me a proper count anymore, but it's progress!

Comment: @TaniaRascia: that's suprising. I addded a link to a fiddle to my answer: as you can see, the queries do not error (NB: the second query assumes `user_id` is the primary key of table `users`).